Object reference not set to an instance of an object .NET MAUI
I am trying to develop an .NET MAUI app that connects to another device using Shiny.BluetoothLE.
BluePage.xaml
using Shiny;
using Shiny.BluetoothLE;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace shinyTest;

public partial class BluePage : ContentPage
{
    private IDisposable _scanSubscription;
    private readonly IBleManager _bleManager;
    private List<string> lst;

    public BluePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _bleManager = Shiny.Hosting.Host.GetService<IBleManager>();
    }
    private async void scan_btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            _scanSubscription = _bleManager.Scan()
        .Where(device => device.Rssi > -70) // Filter based on signal strength (optional)
        .Subscribe(async device =>
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionStatus;
                if (device.Rssi > -60) // Adjust threshold based on your needs
                {
                    connectionStatus = "Likely Connected";
                    //  await DisplayAlert("Response", $"{device.Peripheral.Name}", "Ok");
                    var connectedDevice = device.Peripheral.ConnectAsync();
                    if (connectedDevice != null)
                    {
                        string msg = "Hello World!";
                        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);

                        var uuid = device.Peripheral.Uuid.ToString();
                        var charUUID = Guid.Parse("0000FFF2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
                        await DisplayAlert("Response", $"{uuid}", "Ok");

                        using (var trans = device.Peripheral.TryBeginTransaction())
                        {
                            await trans.Write(device.Peripheral,uuid, charUUID.ToString(), buffer);
                            await DisplayAlert("Response", "Message sent!!", "Ok");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Error", "No devices found", "Ok");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    connectionStatus = "Disconnected";
                    await DisplayAlert("Response", $"{connectionStatus}", "Ok");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Exception", $"{ex.Message}", "Ok");
            }
            
        });
        }    
}

The connected devices are shown properly but when I try to write something it is hitting this exception --- "Object reference not set to an instance of object"
Help appreciated!

Does this answer your question? What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?

private async void scan_btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _scanSubscription = _bleManager.Scan()
        .Where(device => device.Rssi > -70) // Filter based on signal strength
        .Subscribe(async device =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (device?.Peripheral == null)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", "Peripheral is null", "Ok");
                    return;
                }

                string connectionStatus = device.Rssi > -60 ? "Likely Connected" : "Disconnected";
                await DisplayAlert("Response", $"{connectionStatus}", "Ok");

                if (device.Rssi > -60)
                {
                    // Attempt to connect to the device
                    var connectedDevice = await device.Peripheral.ConnectAsync();
                    if (connectedDevice != null)
                    {
                        string msg = "Hello World!";
                        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
                        var uuid = device.Peripheral.Uuid.ToString();
                        var charUUID = Guid.Parse("0000FFF2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
                        await DisplayAlert("Response", $"{uuid}", "Ok");

                        using (var trans = await device.Peripheral.TryBeginTransaction())
                        {
                            if (trans != null)
                            {
                                await trans.Write(device.Peripheral, uuid, charUUID.ToString(), buffer);
                                await DisplayAlert("Response", "Message sent!!", "Ok");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Transaction failed", "Ok");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Failed to connect to device", "Ok");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Response", "Weak Signal", "Ok");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Exception", $"{ex.Message}", "Ok");
            }
        });
}

It seems like your device peripheral is not null and is connected when you attempt to perform operations on it. You might want to ensure that the device is actually connected before attempting to use the Peripheral
once check explicitly if device Peripheral is null or not.

I tried using a boolean variable to check if any device is connected or not. And it is returning true.
Also   await DisplayAlert("Response", $"{uuid}", "Ok");  is returning a uuid!
